# How to retrieve Manual Job Applications from Facebook Page using API in c#?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have implemented Job Posting for our .Net Application. We need to fetch XML Job Applications and Manual Job Applications and mapped data into our existing database.
 XML Job Application is working with App access token. So we can use this as background service. For Manual Job Application, we have found API by which we can retrieve Manual Job Applications using PageId but it  only works with User access token. As mentioned we have to create background service. We have tried to execute API using App access token but it is giving following error.

---

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "E4LF9xlAzNl"
  }
}
```

---

Please advice.